# MLE function with array of parameters

Tags: r

I would like to know how to do the maximum likelihood estimation in R when fitting parameters are given in an array. This is needed when the number of parameters is large. So basically, to fit a normal distribution to the data x, I would like to do something like the following

```
LL <- function(param_array) {
   R = dnorm(x, param_array[1], param_array[2])
  -sum(log(R))
}

mle(LL, start = list(param_array = c(1,1)))
```

(Instead of this original code in the first section of http://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-model-by-maximum-likelihood/) 
If I ran the code above I will get an error

> Error in dnorm(x, param_array[1], param_array[2]) :  argument
>   "param_array" is missing, with no default

Could anyone let me know how to achieve what I want in the correct way?

Comment: So what do people do if they have like 50 parameters? Do they type them in by hand?

Comment: you could see `?bbmle::mle2`, and the `vecpar` argument ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stats4::mle` is not a long function, you can inspect it in your R console:

```
> stats4::mle
```

Note how `start` is handled:

```
start <- sapply(start, eval.parent)
nm <- names(start)
```

**case 1**

If you do:

```
LL <- function(mu, sigma) {
   R = dnorm(x, mu, sigma)
  -sum(log(R))
}

mle(LL, start = list(mu = 1, sigma = 1))
```

you get:

```
nm
#[1] "mu"  "sigma"
```

Also,

```
formalArgs(LL)
#[1] "mu"  "sigma"
```

**case 2**

If you do:

```
LL <- function(param_array) {
   R = dnorm(x, param_array[1], param_array[2])
  -sum(log(R))
}

mle(LL, start = list(param_array = c(1,1)))
```

you get

```
nm
#[1] NULL
```

but

```
formalArgs(LL)
#[1] param_array
```

**The problem**

The evaluation of function `LL` inside `stats::mle` is by matching `nm` to the formal arguments of `LL`. In **case 1**, there is no difficulty in matching, but in **case 2** you get no match, thus you will fail to evaluate `LL`.

---

> So what do people do if they have like 50 parameters? Do they type them in by hand?

Isn't this a bogus argument, after a careful reflection? If you really have 50 parameters, does using an array really save your effort?

First, inside your function `LL`, you have to specify `param_array[1]`, `param_array[2]`, ..., `param_array[50]`, i.e., you still need to manually input 50 parameters into the right positions. While when specifying `start`, you still need to type in a length-50 vector element by element, right? Isn't this the same amount of work, compared with not using an array but a list?